# spring-data-hazelcast @Query annotation gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-data, hazelcast

https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast library used in SpringBootTest retrieves list succesfully when findAll() used as below.

```
@Override
public List<Store> getStores() {
    return storeRepository.findAll();
}
```

However when `@Query` annotation used as below it gives NullPointerException.

```
@Override
public List<Store> (String cityId, String countryId) {
    return storeRepository.getStores(cityId,countryId);
}
```

StoreRepository

```
public interface StoreRepository extends HazelcastRepository<Store,String> {

    @Query("cityId=%s and countryId=%s")
    public List<Store> getStores(String cityId, String countryId);

}
```

Exception is below.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Retrieving a map instance with a null name is not allowed!

    at com.hazelcast.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:59)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.getMap(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:183)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceProxy.getMap(HazelcastInstanceProxy.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.hazelcast.repository.support.StringBasedHazelcastRepositoryQuery.getMap(StringBasedHazelcastRepositoryQuery.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.hazelcast.repository.support.StringBasedHazelcastRepositoryQuery.execute(StringBasedHazelcastRepositoryQuery.java:48)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
```

Is a property missing? If that is the case, why does it work with findAll() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Default `findAll()` method calls Spring Data in `SimpleKeyValueRepository` instance and it consumes `KeyValueTemplate(this instance has HazelcastKeyValueAdapter)` findAll() method.
>
> So, `@Query` annoted queries Hazelcast Spring data implementation's [HazelcastQueryMethod.class](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hazelcast/repository/support/HazelcastQueryMethod.java#L51) looks for `@KeySpace` annotation with value. [StringBasedHazelcastRepositoryQuery.class](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/hazelcast/repository/support/StringBasedHazelcastRepositoryQuery.java#L67) `getMap` method calls hazelcastInstance's `getMap` method with that keySpace's value which is map key.

In short, you need to add `@KeySpace("yourMapName")` annotation to your Store class.

---

Extra information; when you don't put `@KeySpace("yourMapName")` over your class, it will store with exact package name like com.yourpackage.model.Store.